# Provide a template for Angular directive based on scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I am newbie for Angular, and I need to implement interactive map with selectable parts of svg file.

There is my controller, and directives for whole svg map and partial regions.

**ColorPicker controller**

```
app.controller("ColorPicker", function($scope, $timeout, appConfig) {
$scope.colors = [];
$scope.currentColorSet = 0;
$scope.svgTemplateUrl = appConfig.arSvg[$scope.$parent.roomType.id][$scope.$parent.roomStyle.id]+'over.svg'

$scope.alertColor = function(color) {
    console.log(color);
}


});
```

**Map directive**

```
app.directive('svgMap', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'models/livingrooms/Livingroom_01/over.svg',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var svg = $(element).find('svg');
        svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');
        svg.attr('width', '869px');
        svg.attr('height', '489px');
        element.append(svg);

        var regions = element[0].querySelectorAll('path');

        angular.forEach(regions, function (path, key) {
            var regionElement = angular.element(path);
            regionElement.attr("region", "");
            $compile(regionElement)(scope);
        });
    },
}
}]);
```

**Region directive**

```
app.directive('region', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.elementId = element.attr("id");
        scope.stroke = '';
        scope.regionClick = function () {
            console.log(scope.elementId);
        };
        scope.setStroke = function () {
            scope.stroke = '#e5514e';
        };
        scope.removeStroke = function () {
            scope.stroke = '';
        };
        element.attr("ng-click", "regionClick()");
        element.attr("ng-attr-stroke", "{{stroke}}");
        element.attr("ng-mouseenter", "setStroke()");
        element.attr("ng-mouseleave", "removeStroke()");
        element.removeAttr("region");
        $compile(element)(scope);
    }
}
}]);
```

What I need is to dynamically load SVG file as template and compile it and all it regions based on scope variable $scope.svgTemplateUrl

All working fine now if templateUrl is a constant string, how to make it dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you want to load `templateUrl` dynamically then it can be done like this by passing a callback to it.

```
templateUrl: function(element,attrs) {
             return attrs.templateUrl;
           }
```

Now while using the directive-

```
<svgMap template-url="models/livingrooms/Livingroom_01/over.svg"><svgMap>
```

alternative way is to define a scope directive like

```
app.directive('svgMap', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        templatecontenturl: '='
    },
    templateUrl: templatecontenturl,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    },
}
}]);
```

Use it like

```
<svgMap templatecontenturl="svgTemplateUrl"><svgMap>
```

See the http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope on scope variable passing between directives.

Comment: I don't realize why but {{svgTemplateUrl }} is not compiled at time of a call and have value: templateUrl: "{{svgTemplateUrl}}" and not a valid url....

Comment: I see svgTemplateUrl  is defined in controller .try now without {{}}.

Comment: I already did, like that

$scope.svgTemplateUrl ='models/livingrooms/Livingroom_01/over.svg';

but there is no value in attrs.templateUrl;

Comment: if I outtput somwhere in another place {{svgTemplateUrl}} have a url value, but in that attribune it not working

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Comment: latest stable version, 1.4.8

Comment: http://take.ms/8bNyF
Somewhere in a button normal output, but no value in templarecontenturl....

Comment: No no use only svgTemplateUrl.{{}} is not required.it should work

Comment: if I use first approach, the attrs.templateUrl is equal to 'svgTemplateUrl'
if second, i have an error templatecontenturl is not defined